# c++ Reading 3D coordinates from a large array and calculating the distance between them

Tags: c++, arrays, stream

I've got an assignment due that I'm really struggling :

> Write a program that reads input-week6-ad-q3.txt (3D coordinates of 200 points) into arrays and report the followings
>   1. Distances between point1 and others (consider 1st coordinate is point1, 2nd point2,,,.)
>   2. The point which is the closest to point 1 and the distance between point1 and the closest point.

I've tried to start it but I can't get the coordinates in at the moment and I don't even know where to start in finding the closest point. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is what I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 200;
typedef double x_coord[MAX];
typedef double y_coord[MAX];
typedef double z_coord[MAX];

int main()
{
    x_coord x;
    y_coord y;
    z_coord z;
    int count;
    ifstream in_stream;

    in_stream.open("input-week6-ad-q4-2.txt");
    in_stream.get(x, y, z);
    for (count = 0; count < MAX; count++)
    {
        x[count] = x;
        in_stream.get(x);

        y[count] = y;
        in_stream.get(y);

        z[count] = z;
        in_stream.get(z);
    }
    in_stream.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The input file has the points layed out like this:

```
Coordinates of many points  
   x        y         z
-0.06325 0.0359793 0.0420873 
-0.06275 0.0360343 0.0425949 
-0.0645 0.0365101 0.0404362
```

ect.

Comment: Don't think of 'finding the closest point' as a programming question. Think of it as a maths one.  Once you've got the solution on paper you can then start trying to code it

Comment: hint - the fastest way isn't to compare distances; but distances squared!

Comment: [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) returns a single character, which is not what you want. `in_stream >> x[count];` would be an improvement.

Comment: I recommend using a collection (vector or array) of structures.  You could call the struct `Point3d`.  Usually an array of structures is better than parallel arrays (think about synchronization issues).  Also, the processor can load in the elements of a struct into a cache line easier than 3 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second part of your question, generally the distance between points in 2+ dimensional space is called the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

Answer (score 0):

We'll *kill two birds with one stone* here.

Start off by creating a structure for the point:

```
struct Point3d
{
  double x, y, z;
};
```

Next, overload `operator>>` to read in the point values:

```
struct Point3d
{
  double x, y, z;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Point3d& p);
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Point3d& p)
{
  input >> p.x >> p.y >> p.z;
  return input;
}
```

Next, create a database using `std::vector`:
typedef std::vector Database_Type;
Database_Type database;

Here comes the input loop:

```
std::string text_line;
// Ignore the header lines
std::getline(my_data, text_line);
std::getline(my_data, text_line);
Point3d p;
while (my_data >> p)
{
  database.push_back(p);
}
```

You can insert a distance function into your structure:

```
struct Point3d
{
  //...
  double distance(const Point3d& p) const;
};
double
Point3d::
distance(const Point3d& p) const
{
  const double x_diff_squared = (x - p.x) * (x - p.x);
  const double y_diff_squared = (y - p.y) * (y - p.y);
  const double z_diff_squared = (z - p.z) * (z - p.z);
  return sqrt(x_diff_squared + y_diff_squared + z_diff_squared);
}
```

The above method will allow you do stuff like:

```
const double distance_p1_p2 = database[0].distance(database[1]);
```

**Edit 1: Freestanding distance function**
Alternatively, you could make a free-standing distance function:

```
double Distance(const Point3d& p1, const Point3d& p2)
{
      const double x_diff_squared = (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x);
      const double y_diff_squared = (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y);
      const double z_diff_squared = (p1.z - p2.z) * (p1.z - p2.z);
      return sqrt(x_diff_squared + y_diff_squared + z_diff_squared);
}
```

Apply it as:

```
const distance_p1_p2 = Distance(database[0], database[1]);
```